# Xamarin Multilingual App Ios App store Blank Problem

Tags: xamarin, mobile, app-store, multilingual

I have an app developed with Xamarin. Now i did Multilingual updates. Our Simulator test and Phone tests no problem but, when we publish App Store, Xaml files multilingual changes working, Cs file multilingual changes not working. All items blank.

Android publish no problem. Test Phone no problem, Simulator no problem. But when appstore publish, multilingual items blank.

Where we be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you translating the App? Resx? plist files, somehow else?

Comment: Yes, used resx.

Comment: Did you use third-party package to implement Multilingual or not ?

Comment: No. didn't any third-party for Multilingual.

Comment: What do you mean by `xaml files multilingual changes working, Cs file multilingual changes not working.` ?

Comment: Hi Colex, Today resolved! this is not multilingual problem. When we publish for release with iphone 6, other all iphone models some areas full blank. When we publish with generic all ok. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today resolved! this is not multilingual problem. When we publish for release with iphone 6, other all iphone models some areas full blank. When we publish with generic all ok. Thanks for answers